# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'

Tags: python, class, gurobi

I have a problem with adding three expressions in my objective function. I used `quicksum` to build each expression. However, when I try to add them together I get an error that I cannot use +/- operands on class 'generator'.

Here is the last part of my code:

```
# the shipping cost expression
expr_sc = []
for j in J:
    for k in K:
        expr_sc.append(quicksum(r_jk[(j, k)]*x[(i, j, k)]) for i in I)

m.setObjective((quicksum(item_rev) for item_rev in expr_rev) -
               ((quicksum(item_pc) for item_pc in expr_pc) + (quicksum(item_sc) for item_sc in expr_sc)),
               GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

## Update:

here is the actual problem that I am trying to solve:
[Objective Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFHyM.gif)
The problem is I don't know how to write this expression in Gurobi Python!!

Comment: What do you expect using the operator `+` on the expressions to do? I haven't used `quicksum()` myself, but from the documentation it says that it returns `An expression that represents the sum of the terms in the input list.` and from your error I would expect you're getting a generator object returned as explained in section 5.2.6 of [The Python Expressions Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(quicksum(item_rev) for item_rev in expr_rev)` evaluates to a generator expression.

If the one line `for` loop is inside the parenthesis - `(...)` - you get a generator object. Here's a small example to illustrate what I mean:

```
>>> (x for x in range(5)) # shorthand for creating generators
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb74308ec>
```

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=generator%20express#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) for more info.

It seems you're trying to pass individual items from given lists to `quicksum`, but instead you're creating generators, unintentionally.

To fix this error, directly pass the objects to `quicksum`:

```
m.setObjective(
    quicksum(expr_rev) - (quicksum(expr_pc) + quicksum(expr_sc)),
    GRB.MAXIMIZE
)
```

**UPDATE:**

There also seems to be a problem at

```
expr_sc.append(quicksum(r_jk[(j, k)]*x[(i, j, k)]) for i in I)
```

Change that line like this:

```
expr_sc.append(quicksum(r_jk[(j, k)] * x[(i, j, k)] for i in I))
```

Comment: This seems to defeat the whole point of generators, _and_ it builds two unnecessary lists since `quicksum` accepts generator arguments.

Comment: Generator expressions do not need to be parenthesized if they are the sole argument.

Comment: Also, it might be easier to just use `iter` to create these generators. But why would that even be done if each object can be passed to `quicksum` directly?

Comment: @JaredGoguen That's a valid point. I was thinking about that but I chose to keep my code consistent with OP's original code. Nevertheless, I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I implemented your code and this is what I get `gurobipy.GurobiError: Unsupported type (<class 'generator'>) for LinExpr addition argument`

Comment: @RezaA. I've updated the answer with more code. If you still get any errors, update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: @xyres I just edited the question, thanks for the help!!