# Error_Generator expression_spyder(python 3.6)

Tags: expression, generator

I develop mathematical model using gurobi solver, in python.
I get the following error while running:

> **SyntaxError:** *Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument*

My constraint is:
[image]

My code is:

```
for s in S:
    m.addConstr(sum(x[s,s0,c,i] for s0 in S0 for c in C for i in D,s!=p) == 1,'C_3')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, everything comes whenever you add that comma: `,s!=p`.

I just emulated your code with a model I'm working on, and I obviously got the same error. Look around (e.g. [if else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)), and you will see that the only mistake you had was that the iterator within the generator wasn't well specified. That means, you had to use an `if` clause in order to achieve what you wanted:

```
for s in S:
    m.addConstr( 
     quicksum(x[s,s0,c,i] for s0 in S0 for c in C for i in D if s!=p) == 1,
      'C_3_'+str(s) )
```

By the way, as included in the code, you should use `quicksum` instead of `sum`. Furthermore, I would suggest to try changing the order of the iterators; in other words, it's not the same for a computer to enumerate a list of 5 elements 1000 times than to enumerate 5 times a list of 1000 elements, and this is something quite important in Python timing.

As a side note, I got into this question while looking for this:
[TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476155/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-generator-and-generator)

Comment: Thank you too much!

Comment: No problem @Tahirov